# Why does EF Core inserts before deleting instead of deleting and then inserting when updating a child list of a model?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I'm Entity Framework Core 3 and I'm using the Pomelo MySQL provider.
I'm trying to update a child property with:

```cs
model.Items = collection;
```

where `model` is an entity that exists in the database and `collection` is a `ICollection<Item>` of new entities to be set for that list.

When I then run:

```cs
dbContext.Models.Update(model);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(ct);
```

I notice a strange behavior (by looking at the EF Core query logs): previously existing items associated with the model are not removed immediately but only after the new items in `collection` are inserted.

This causes an integrity constraint error on the database because for a brief moment (between the insertion and later deletion) there are duplicate values for certain unique columns.

I'm wondering if this behavior is configurable somehow and why are related entities removed only after insertion when viceversa seems safer.

---

#### How to reproduce

In order to reproduce the issue you can use this `docker-compose.yml` file to setup a MySQL 8 database:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  database:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: So61383388
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: So61383388
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
      - "33060:33060"
```

and then run this program:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<IceCreamVariation> Variations { get; set; } = new HashSet<IceCreamVariation>();
    }

    public class IceCreamVariation
    {
        public int IceCreamVariationId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }

        public IceCream IceCream { get; set; }

        public ICollection<IceCreamVariationQuality> Qualities { get; set; } = new HashSet<IceCreamVariationQuality>();
    }

    public class IceCreamVariationQuality
    {
        public int IceCreamVariationQualityId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int IceCreamVariationId { get; set; }

        public IceCreamVariation IceCreamVariation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IceCreamVariation> IceCreamVariations { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql(
                    "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=root;database=So61383388",
                    b => b.ServerVersion("8.0"))
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>()
                .HasData(
                    new IceCream {IceCreamId = 1, Name = "Vanilla"}
                );

            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCreamVariation>()
                .HasData(
                    new IceCreamVariation {IceCreamVariationId = 1, Name = "Double Vanilla Bourbon", IceCreamId = 1},
                    new IceCreamVariation {IceCreamVariationId = 2, Name = "Vanilla Caramel", IceCreamId = 1}
                );

            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCreamVariationQuality>()
                .HasData(
                    new IceCreamVariationQuality {IceCreamVariationQualityId = 1, Name = "Fresh", IceCreamVariationId = 1},
                    new IceCreamVariationQuality {IceCreamVariationQualityId = 2, Name = "Yummy", IceCreamVariationId = 1},
                    new IceCreamVariationQuality {IceCreamVariationQualityId = 3, Name = "Woops", IceCreamVariationId = 2}
                );
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var iceCreamWithOldVariations = context.IceCreams
                    .Include(i => i.Variations)
                        .ThenInclude(i => i.Qualities)
                    .OrderBy(i => i.IceCreamId)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                Debug.Assert(iceCreamWithOldVariations.Variations.Count == 2);

                var vanillaIceCream = iceCreamWithOldVariations;
                vanillaIceCream.Variations.Clear();
                vanillaIceCream.Variations.Add(
                    new IceCreamVariation 
                    {
                        Name = "Vanilla Cheesecake", 
                        Qualities = new IceCreamVariationQuality[]
                        {
                            new IceCreamVariationQuality { Name = "Healthy" },
                        },
                    });
                vanillaIceCream.Variations.Add(
                    new IceCreamVariation 
                    {
                        Name = "Vanilla Cheesecake", 
                        Qualities = new IceCreamVariationQuality[]
                        {
                            new IceCreamVariationQuality { Name = "Fresh" },
                            new IceCreamVariationQuality { Name = "Cool" },
                        },
                    });

                context.SaveChanges();

                var iceCreamWithNewVariations = context.IceCreams
                    .Include(i => i.Variations)
                        .ThenInclude(i => i.Qualities)
                    .OrderBy(i => i.IceCreamId)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                Debug.Assert(iceCreamWithNewVariations.Variations.Count == 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with this console .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

using:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d
dotnet run
```

If you see the logs:

- the qualities are removed first (which is ok)
- then new variations are added (which is incorrect)
- the old variations are removed (which should happen before the new variations are added)

This behavior doesn't seem to happen if you don't have the nested qualities for each variation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a **workaround**, see "Workaround" below.

---

What is your specific reason for using [DbSet.Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-3.1)? It has as very special purpose that has to do with tracking.

Instead, it should be enough to remove the old items and adding the new:

```cs
model.Items.Remove(someOldItem); // or use other `Remove` methods
model.Items.AddRange(newItems);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Here is a complete example how it works:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<IceCreamVariation> Variations { get; set; } = new HashSet<IceCreamVariation>();
    }

    public class IceCreamVariation
    {
        public int IceCreamVariationId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }

        public IceCream IceCream { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IceCreamVariation> IceCreamVariations { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql(
                    "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=So61383388",
                    b => b.ServerVersion("8.0.20-mysql"))
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>()
                .HasData(
                    new IceCream {IceCreamId = 1, Name = "Vanilla"},
                    new IceCream {IceCreamId = 2, Name = "Chocolate"}
                );

            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCreamVariation>()
                .HasData(
                    new IceCreamVariation {IceCreamVariationId = 1, Name = "Double Vanilla Bourbon", IceCreamId = 1},
                    new IceCreamVariation {IceCreamVariationId = 2, Name = "Vanilla Caramel", IceCreamId = 1},
                    new IceCreamVariation {IceCreamVariationId = 3, Name = "Chocolate Hazelnut", IceCreamId = 2}
                );
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var iceCreamsWithOldVariations = context.IceCreams
                    .Include(i => i.Variations)
                    .OrderBy(i => i.IceCreamId)
                    .ToList();

                Debug.Assert(iceCreamsWithOldVariations.Count == 2);
                Debug.Assert(iceCreamsWithOldVariations[0].Variations.Count == 2);
                Debug.Assert(iceCreamsWithOldVariations[1].Variations.Count == 1);

                var vanillaIceCream = iceCreamsWithOldVariations[0];
                var vanillaCaramelVariation = iceCreamsWithOldVariations[0].Variations.First();
                vanillaIceCream.Variations.Remove(vanillaCaramelVariation);
                vanillaIceCream.Variations.Add(new IceCreamVariation {Name = "Vanilla Cheesecake"});
                vanillaIceCream.Variations.Add(new IceCreamVariation {Name = "Vanilla-Lemon"});

                var cholocateIceCream = iceCreamsWithOldVariations[1];
                cholocateIceCream.Variations.Clear();
                cholocateIceCream.Variations.Add(new IceCreamVariation {Name = "Chocolate Fudge Brownie"});
                cholocateIceCream.Variations.Add(new IceCreamVariation {Name = "Chocolate-Peanut Butter"});

                context.SaveChanges();

                var iceCreamsWithNewVariations = context.IceCreams
                    .Include(i => i.Variations)
                    .OrderBy(i => i.IceCreamId)
                    .ToList();

                Debug.Assert(iceCreamsWithNewVariations.Count == 2);
                Debug.Assert(iceCreamsWithNewVariations[0].Variations.Count == 3);
                Debug.Assert(iceCreamsWithNewVariations[1].Variations.Count == 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following SQL statements are being generated, which work as expected:

```sql
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      CREATE DATABASE `So61383388`;

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (38ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      CREATE TABLE `IceCreams` (
          `IceCreamId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK_IceCreams` PRIMARY KEY (`IceCreamId`)
      );

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (35ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      CREATE TABLE `IceCreamVariations` (
          `IceCreamVariationId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          `IceCreamId` int NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK_IceCreamVariations` PRIMARY KEY (`IceCreamVariationId`),
          CONSTRAINT `FK_IceCreamVariations_IceCreams_IceCreamId` FOREIGN KEY (`IceCreamId`) REFERENCES `IceCreams` (`IceCreamId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
      );

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      INSERT INTO `IceCreams` (`IceCreamId`, `Name`)
      VALUES (1, 'Vanilla');

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      INSERT INTO `IceCreams` (`IceCreamId`, `Name`)
      VALUES (2, 'Chocolate');

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      INSERT INTO `IceCreamVariations` (`IceCreamVariationId`, `IceCreamId`, `Name`)
      VALUES (1, 1, 'Double Vanilla Bourbon');

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      INSERT INTO `IceCreamVariations` (`IceCreamVariationId`, `IceCreamId`, `Name`)
      VALUES (2, 1, 'Vanilla Caramel');

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      INSERT INTO `IceCreamVariations` (`IceCreamVariationId`, `IceCreamId`, `Name`)
      VALUES (3, 2, 'Chocolate Hazelnut');

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (30ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      CREATE INDEX `IX_IceCreamVariations_IceCreamId` ON `IceCreamVariations` (`IceCreamId`);

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT `i`.`IceCreamId`, `i`.`Name`, `i0`.`IceCreamVariationId`, `i0`.`IceCreamId`, `i0`.`Name`
      FROM `IceCreams` AS `i`
      LEFT JOIN `IceCreamVariations` AS `i0` ON `i`.`IceCreamId` = `i0`.`IceCreamId`
      ORDER BY `i`.`IceCreamId`, `i0`.`IceCreamVariationId`

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[@p0='1', @p1='3', @p2='1', @p3='Vanilla Cheesecake' (Size = 4000), @p4='1', @p5='Vanilla-Lemon' (Size = 4000), @p6='2', @p7='Chocolate Fudge Brownie' (Size = 4000), @p8='2', @p9='Chocolate-Peanut Butter' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      DELETE FROM `IceCreamVariations`
      WHERE `IceCreamVariationId` = @p0;
      SELECT ROW_COUNT();

      DELETE FROM `IceCreamVariations`
      WHERE `IceCreamVariationId` = @p1;
      SELECT ROW_COUNT();

      INSERT INTO `IceCreamVariations` (`IceCreamId`, `Name`)
      VALUES (@p2, @p3);
      SELECT `IceCreamVariationId`
      FROM `IceCreamVariations`
      WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1 AND `IceCreamVariationId` = LAST_INSERT_ID();

      INSERT INTO `IceCreamVariations` (`IceCreamId`, `Name`)
      VALUES (@p4, @p5);
      SELECT `IceCreamVariationId`
      FROM `IceCreamVariations`
      WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1 AND `IceCreamVariationId` = LAST_INSERT_ID();

      INSERT INTO `IceCreamVariations` (`IceCreamId`, `Name`)
      VALUES (@p6, @p7);
      SELECT `IceCreamVariationId`
      FROM `IceCreamVariations`
      WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1 AND `IceCreamVariationId` = LAST_INSERT_ID();

      INSERT INTO `IceCreamVariations` (`IceCreamId`, `Name`)
      VALUES (@p8, @p9);
      SELECT `IceCreamVariationId`
      FROM `IceCreamVariations`
      WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1 AND `IceCreamVariationId` = LAST_INSERT_ID();

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT `i`.`IceCreamId`, `i`.`Name`, `i0`.`IceCreamVariationId`, `i0`.`IceCreamId`, `i0`.`Name`
      FROM `IceCreams` AS `i`
      LEFT JOIN `IceCreamVariations` AS `i0` ON `i`.`IceCreamId` = `i0`.`IceCreamId`
      ORDER BY `i`.`IceCreamId`, `i0`.`IceCreamVariationId`
```

> I'm wondering if this behavior is configurable somehow and why are related entities removed only after insertion when viceversa seems safer.

You can see, that the `DELETE` statements are being executed *before* the `INSERT` statements.

---

**Update**

With the new sample code you provided, I am able to reproduce the issue. This seems to be a bug in EF Core (not Pomelo), because the same behavior can be reproduced with SQL Server:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<IceCreamVariation> Variations { get; set; } = new HashSet<IceCreamVariation>();
    }

    public class IceCreamVariation
    {
        public int IceCreamVariationId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int UniqueId { get; set; }
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }

        public IceCream IceCream { get; set; }

        public ICollection<IceCreamVariationQuality> Qualities { get; set; } = new HashSet<IceCreamVariationQuality>();
    }

    public class IceCreamVariationQuality
    {
        public int IceCreamVariationQualityId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int IceCreamVariationId { get; set; }

        public IceCreamVariation IceCreamVariation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IceCreamVariation> IceCreamVariations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IceCreamVariationQuality> IceCreamVariationQualities { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=So61383388_01")
                //.UseMySql(
                //    "server=127.0.0.1;port=3308;user=root;password=;database=So61383388_01",
                //    b => b.ServerVersion("8.0.20-mysql"))
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>()
                .HasData(
                    new IceCream {IceCreamId = 1, Name = "Vanilla"}
                );

            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCreamVariation>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.UniqueId);

                    entity.HasData(
                        new IceCreamVariation
                        {
                            IceCreamVariationId = 1,
                            Name = "Double Vanilla Bourbon",
                            UniqueId = 42, // this value is part of a unique index
                            IceCreamId = 1
                        }
                    );
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCreamVariationQuality>()
                .HasData(
                    new IceCreamVariationQuality
                    {
                        IceCreamVariationQualityId = 1,
                        Name = "Yummy",
                        IceCreamVariationId = 1
                    }
                );
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var iceCreamWithOldVariations = context.IceCreams
                    .Include(i => i.Variations)
                        .ThenInclude(i => i.Qualities)
                    .OrderBy(i => i.IceCreamId)
                    .First();

                Debug.Assert(iceCreamWithOldVariations.Variations.Count == 1);
                Debug.Assert(iceCreamWithOldVariations.Variations.Single().UniqueId == 42);
                Debug.Assert(iceCreamWithOldVariations.Variations.Single().Qualities.First().Name == "Yummy");

                iceCreamWithOldVariations.Variations.Clear();
                iceCreamWithOldVariations.Variations.Add(
                    new IceCreamVariation 
                    {
                        Name = "Vanilla Cheesecake",
                        UniqueId = 42, // use same value again; should work because previous entity was removed
                        Qualities = new[]
                        {
                            new IceCreamVariationQuality { Name = "Healthy" },
                        },
                    });

                context.SaveChanges();

                var iceCreamWithNewVariations = context.IceCreams
                    .Include(i => i.Variations)
                        .ThenInclude(i => i.Qualities)
                    .OrderBy(i => i.IceCreamId)
                    .First();

                Debug.Assert(iceCreamWithNewVariations.Variations.Count == 1);
                Debug.Assert(iceCreamWithNewVariations.Variations.Single().UniqueId == 42);
                Debug.Assert(iceCreamWithNewVariations.Variations.Single().Qualities.First().Name == "Healthy");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If executed when the `UniqueId` property has been declared, an exception is being thrown and the generated SQL is even more unexpected:

```sql
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (15ms) [Parameters=[@p0='1'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      DELETE FROM [IceCreamVariationQualities]
      WHERE [IceCreamVariationQualityId] = @p0;
      SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[@p1='1', @p0='Vanilla Cheesecake' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      UPDATE [IceCreamVariations] SET [Name] = @p0
      WHERE [IceCreamVariationId] = @p1;
      SELECT [IceCreamVariationId]
      FROM [IceCreamVariations]
      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [IceCreamVariationId] = scope_identity();
```

Here, an `UPDATE` statement has been generated to change the name of a `IceCreamVariations` entity (which is wrong), that assumes the entity has just been inserted (which is not the case), because it uses `scope_identity()`.

---

**Workaround:**

The discussion continued on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20870).

There, @smitpatel suggested to try `entity.HasIndex(e => e.UniqueId).IsUnique()` instead of `entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.UniqueId)`, which works as expected.

So defining a unique index instead of an alternate key in the model definition is a valid workaround for this issue:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<IceCreamVariation>(
        entity =>
        {
            // This does not work:
            // entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.UniqueId);

            // This *does* work:
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UniqueId)
                .IsUnique();

            entity.HasData(
                new IceCreamVariation
                {
                    IceCreamVariationId = 1,
                    Name = "Double Vanilla Bourbon",
                    UniqueId = 42, // this value is part of a unique index
                    IceCreamId = 1
                }
            );
        });

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Is `DbSet.Update` causing these problems?

Comment: Even removing the `DbSet.Update` call and using `model.Items.Clear()` the error remains.

Comment: @ShoeDiamente I added a fully working example console project, so you can take a look at how it works and can also test it on your end.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I've modified your C# program a little by adding another sub model to `IceCreamVariation` so that it's equivalent to my use case: https://pastebin.com/pnJniaMy.
As you can see the output shows that first `IceCreamVariationQuality`s are removed and then `IceCreamVariation`s are inserted before the old ones are removed. This is my log for my example: https://pastebin.com/0W3JXhgw.

Comment: I've also updated the question with the content of that pastebin.

Comment: It's a bug in EF Core. See my answer for further details. Do you want me to report it to the EF Core team, or do you want to do it yourself?

Comment: Thanks, you can find the issue link here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20870. I'll accept the answer as soon as they confirm it's a bug.

Comment: Hi, I've accepted the answer. It's not technically a bug given that the problem was that I had forgot to configure the indexes on the EF Core side (database first). Anyway, thanks very much for the help.

Comment: No problem. We found the alternate key bug during the discussion, so due to this question, EF Core will be improved for this case for .NET 5.